# Issues SSHing from Windows host to Linux guest

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m trying to SSH from Windows host to Linux guest. Rather than using PuTTY and the like I’m trying to use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

In VirtualBox I have the network settings as "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter".  From Windows command prompt I can ping the VM just fine, but can’t SSH or ping from the Bash command prompt. Note: I had to run bash as admin to get ping to work.

Can anyone confirm or deny that VirtualBox's host only adapter excludes the Windows bash terminal?

I'm not even sure how it’s implemented, so it’s not inconceivable it would be considered a “different” OS or possibly run on a different network hidden to the user.

Comment: A host-only adapter is restricted to interaction with the host, so you'll only be able to talk to the machine running virtualbox. But it isn't clear how you are set up.  Do you have a linux box running virtualbox, and Windows inside that virtualbox, and then running bash from inside Windows?  And the "outer" linux box is the one you are trying to get to?

Comment: Windows 10 is the host OS (outer), Linux is the guest (inner).  Check out Windows Subsystem for Linux - it's a minimal Ubuntu port that runs on top of Windows.  This isn't the VM I'm speaking of, it's separate and I'm just trying to use it for SSH.  I'm not sure if Ubuntu is considered a different OS or on a different network.  The question is specifically how Ubuntu is ported to Windows in that manner.

Comment: Yeah, this will be a challenge to work out.  In all likelihood, bash cannot see the vb interface, but the standard tools for viewing the state of the network interfaces and routing table don't yet work in bash for windows.

Comment: I've noticed lol...  I'm just using a different ssh client for the time being, but would like to see docs on how "integrated" Bash is with Windows itself, and how it could be made to be seen as the same host.